# adding line break on pseudo element

Tags: css, element

After each h2 I want to append and style a dash and after that a line break.

I tried the following:

```
h2:after {
    content: '\A\2014';
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 70px;
}
```

It does work in general, but when I in- or decrease the font-size, the space both over and under the dash change, instead of just the dash-size.

I also tried adding a `line-height: 0.6em;` but it seems to move everything around.

At the moment I'm getting this:

[image: At the moment I'm getting this:]

I want to get this, being able to change the space:

[image: I want to get this, being able to change the space:]

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uzVhz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use borders?

```
h2 { border-bottom: 4px solid #000; }
```

and then you could just adjust the padding on the bottom of the H2:

```
h2 { padding-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 4px solid #000; }
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

To keep the dash the same width regardless of the title width I simply styled the :after pseudo element with a border and display block: http://jsfiddle.net/uzVhz/2

Comment: I dont use borders because I want the dash to be exactly the same width, no matter how long the h2 is.

Comment: You could float the element and then clear it. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzVhz/1/

Comment: @MatthewR. I think he means he wants the dash to be 40px (or whatever), no matter how long the text in the H2 is, which won't happen even with floating.

Comment: Yes exactly what jblasco said. Sorry, my english might be a bit crappy

Comment: You can still use borders and padding. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/uzVhz/2/

Comment: Thank you. One last thing: is it possible to change the space between the dash and the lorem ipsum text? Padding-bottom doesn't work?

Comment: Nvm.. I should get some fresh air, have been stuck on the original question for hours now.. Of course margin-bottom should do the trick!